# Firedac centralized query management

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, firedac

Is there a way in Firedac-Delphi to manage all queries executed on sql server from one place? The goal is to change the where clause for all queries (before they open or execute), but write the code in one place and not all over the application.

Comment: You can have a collection of query objects (or use connection's `DataSets` property) and in their commands use macro (substitution variable).

Comment: I have an existing application with tfddatasets on forms and tfddatasets 
 created on runtime. Is there a way (with fdmanager maybe) to handle any tfddataset before open without having to change every query all over the application?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? Are we talking here about `TFDQuery` objects (e.g. with different SQL commands)? If not, could you elaborate your component setup (are they linked somehow)? Are they placed in different modules (forms)? If so, can you centralize them into a single data module? Are they using single connection object?

Comment: datasets should be on data modules. Create a base datamodule, inherit all other datamodules from this one and put your datasets on the inherited datamodules. Now you can write code in your base datamodule just once that will be able to find all datasets and do with them wathever you want to

Comment: Guys, I am not a beginner.

Comment: I am talking about an existing delphi application where datasets are in different locations in code (some in datamodules, some created in code etc.). Firedac gives FDManager which has a Connections property where all connections created by app are registered. Is there something similar for my case?

Comment: I've already gave you an advice then. Connection object has `DataSets` collection. You can check there for query objects (if we are talking about query objects), and use substitution variable macros to assign desired `WHERE` clause. I understood your question, but I'm trying to tell you that there is no such manager available (manager that would be able to substitute somehow magically `WHERE` clauses in commands for all intended dataset objects; which would be difficult to implement for almost no usage).